# Text email notifications have broken tags

Tags: bug, questions, email, email-notification

The text version of email notifications have only the first tag listed.  Random example from my mail box below -- note the "Tagged: list".

```
[How is the value of (list 'quote '5) = ''5 rather than '(quote 5) or
'(''5)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226219/how-is-the-value-of
-list-quote-5-5-rather-than-quote-5-or-5)

It seems that Common Lisp does treat (list 'quote 'x) in a special way.
For example, the value of (list 'oddp '5) is '(oddp 5) while the value
of (list 'quote '5) is ''5. In other words, the quote ...

Tagged: list

by [anonemba](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1343628/anonemba) on
http://stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Anyone?  These emails are really much less useful, and it sounds like something that is easy to fix.